# MySQL : Comparing values of two different colums from a same table

Tags: mysql

I would like compare the value of two colums from a single table, and UPDATE another colums in function of results, in MySql. Values are on the same row.

Example:

If value COL A > value Col B ==> Col C = "player1"

If value COL A < value Col B ==> Col C = "player2"

How could i do that ?

Something like :
UPDATE table SET col C = "player1" WHERE ...

Edit :

So i just try with CASE...

```
UPDATE partie SET col C =  
CASE
  WHEN Col A > Col B THEN 'player1'
  WHEN Col A < Col B THEN 'player2'
  ELSE 'deuce' 
END
WHERE .... ;
```

Is it correct in Mysql ?

Many thanks

Comment: Presumably Players 1 and 2 are on different rows?

Comment: values of COL A, B, C are on the same row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either do so in two different queries:

```
UPDATE table SET C = 'player1' WHERE a > b;
UPDATE table SET C = 'player2' WHERE a < b;
```

Or try this one liner:

```
UPDATE table SET C = IF(a > b, 'player1', 'player2')
```

Do note:

- What do you want to happen when a = b?
- Without further filtering all of the above will make for full table scans, so very heavyweight for large tables.

Comment: well done and i forgot the case when a = b but i think i gonna find ! If i want to add a condition at the WHERE i need to put AND ? right ?

Comment: Correct, put an "AND some_condition_that_holds_true". You can of course nest the `IF` statement, or use a `CASE` statement instead.

Comment: Shlomi, ty, i try with CASE . It seems to be neater... Could you tell me if it s correct ? ty

Comment: @user2971617 . . . `case` is standard SQL so I prefer it.  In terms of functionality, though, `case` and `if` would be the same in this context.  So, `case` is fine.

Comment: @user2971617 both ways just fine

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
<?php
if ($Cola > $Colb){
UPDATE $tableName SET ColC = "player1";
}
else{
UPDATE $tableName SET ColC = "Player 2";
}
?>
```

Comment: er where did php come from?

Comment: And that's going set every row in the table based on a test on one row.

Comment: Wasn't me who -1'd you but I can understand why they did.

Comment: I just did it in php, the same could be done in any language. He didn't say what language he was using besides mysql. This was an example of how to set it... obviously he knows the WHERE as he didn't mention any of that so how am I supposed to know the WHERE? Sounds to me like it is one table with one row... As he mentioned earlier it is one row with cola colb colc etc...

Comment: The language to do queries is in sql unless you go down the ORM route and the OPs does an update on every row based on each row. Even if you used an ORM doing this sort of query client side in any language is not a good idea.

Comment: What are you talking about tony lol? We all know he is using SQL... My answer used mysql with php... It could be altered with any language. It did the same thing as the other answer that was posted did.

Comment: No it isn't. To use PHP, or C#, or even machine code, you have to write something to pull the data out of the database, do the logic and then send it back. That's wildly inefficient. You only do that, if you are already pulling all the data anyway, or the logic cannot be implemented in the DB.

Comment: Ok I see what your saying.